# PHP echo statement position and styling control

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

This is a slightly simple question, however I cannot recall how to control PHP output within an HTML page. More specifically, I want to control the position of an `echo` statement (part of an `else` statement) using css and tags within the HTML:

```
if($row == 1)
{
    echo '<div id="errormsg">This username is already taken</div>';
}
else
{
    $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, admin) VALUES
    (null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
    echo '<div id="create-success">Successfully added user!</div>';
}
```

I can control some things using the internal `<div>` tags as shown above, but how can I have it positioned in relation to the HTML?

Comment: I understand that, so as all my php comes before my html can the position of some specific php elements be controlled somewhere within the html?

Comment: PHP creates a HTML page. The HTML page is sent to the browser. The HTML can contain Classes  and IDs on the elements (id="something" or class="somethingelse") you then can 'style' these using CSS. You refer to each class or ID and say I want to be aligned X or font size Z font color Y etc etc... See my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: For more information on 'controlling the style' please see [css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/DEFAULT.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you can do:

```
if($row == 1)
{
    $error = '<div id="errormsg">This username is already taken</div>';
}
else
{
    $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, admin) VALUES
    (null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
    echo '<div id="create-success">Successfully added user!</div>';
}
```

and use the `$error` variable where you want to display it, e.g., in your *view.php* file:

```
<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
```

This is just a quick fix, please learn more about [MVC and how to separate your view from your logic](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/).

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you have successfully added id's.

You need to add styling for these IDs in your stylesheet (incase either are called).

For example.

```
#errormsg{
//css here
}
#create-success{
//css here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but supposed you have your HTML page and PHP code inside it:

```
<div>
<?php

   if ($row == 1) {
      echo "This username is already taken";
   } else {
      $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, admin) VALUES
(null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
      echo "Successfully added user!";
   }

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your result from the coding side is, you just put on the conditions, or use the code as follows:

```
if($row == 1)
{
    $msg = '<div id="errormsg">This username is already taken</div>';
}
else
{
    $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, admin) VALUES (null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Can't insert data");
    if($add) {
        $msg = '<div id="create-success">Successfully added user!</div>';
    } else {
        $msg = 'Error in adding record';
    }
}
```

and finally use the `$msg` variable in your PHP or HTML side as follows:

```
<?php if($msg) { echo $msg; }?>
```